# FreeBSD and Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, freebsd

Can I run FreeBSD on Raspberry Pi 3?

I also have a Raspberry Pi 1 B+ has issues booting FreeBSD: It ends up in a "mountroot" prompt.

Comment: At this moment there isn't any release of FreeBSD for Raspberry Pi 3.
You can check https://wiki.freebsd.org/FreeBSD/arm/Raspberry%20Pi and http://raspbsd.org/ for future releases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FreeBSD - easiest way to install on my RPi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3288/freebsd-easiest-way-to-install-on-my-rpi)

Answer (score 6):

The fine folks at RaspBSD provide an image for the Pi 3.

You can download it at [RaspBSD on the RaspberryPi](http://www.raspbsd.org/raspberrypi.html).

Answer (score 3):

At the moment there is no out-of-the-box FreeBSD build for Raspberry Pi 3.

But they are on it ([see freebsd-arm mailing list](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-arm/2016-August/014632.html)).

For your RPi 1: Try one of the recent 11.0-RC2 or 12.0-CURRENT images from https://www.freebsd.org/where.html.

They shall boot fine.

Answer (score 2):

It is being little late to answer this question. But, I am answering this for someone who is or will be going to search for the same question in or after 2018, then this will help.

I have installed **FreeBSD 12.0-current** on my **Raspberry Pi 3** with 16GB SD-CARD.

I am using **USB-TTL converter** to access serial console and then via **minicom**.

I think `sshd` starts at boot but you need to setup wireless or wired connection.

Either you can use LAN cable to share internet from your PC to Raspberry Pi 3 or you can also use the simple method is just plug the wifi adapter and at the time of writing this answer I haven't checked the default built-in Broadcom wifi support.

I had even asked the question regarding with built-in wireless in 2017.
Below is the response from FreeBSD community in 2017.

> [prev in list] [next in list] [prev in thread] [next in thread]
>
> List:       freebsd-arm Subject:    Re: Support for Raspberry Pi 3
>   wifi broadcom driver in FreeBSD From:       Ilya Bakulin  Date:       2017-06-20 9:36:17 Message-ID:
>   9d29575ccb57d1543ec78705bfd001b4 () bakulin ! de [Download message
>   RAW]
>
> Hi Neeraj,
>
> no, wireless chip of RPi3 is not supported in FreeBSD. The support
>   depends on the new SD/SDIO stack integration. Once it is  integrated,
>   someone has to write a driver for the chip. No ETAs on both tasks.
>
> On 2017-06-16 06:04, Neeraj Pal wrote:
>
> > Hello all,
> >
> > I want to know about wireless driver support for *Raspberry Pi 3*.
> >
> > Is there any support for Raspberry Pi 3  wireless Broadcom (*brcmfmac*)
> >     driver?
> >     Because i feels difficulty to set-up wireless in Raspberry Pi 3 
> >     (installed
> >     *FreeBSD*).
> >
> > *Details :[root@rpi3 /usr/home/raspberry]# *uname -a
> >     *FreeBSD rpi3 12.0-CURRENT FreeBSD 12.0-CURRENT #0 r318898M: Thu May 25
> >     15:07:15 MDT 2017
> >     raspberry@hive.raspbsd.org:/usr/home/brd/rpi3/crochet/work/obj/arm64.aarch64/usr/src/sys/GENERIC
> >     arm64*
> >
> > ---
> >
> > freebsd-arm@freebsd.org mailing list
> >     https://lists.freebsd.org/mailman/listinfo/freebsd-arm
> >     To unsubscribe, send any mail to "freebsd-arm-unsubscribe@freebsd.org"
>
> --  Mit freundlichen GrÃ¼ÃŸen, Ilya Bakulin
>   _______________________________________________ freebsd-arm@freebsd.org mailing list
>   https://lists.freebsd.org/mailman/listinfo/freebsd-arm To unsubscribe,
>   send any mail to "freebsd-arm-unsubscribe@freebsd.org" [prev in list]
>   [next in list] [prev in thread] [next in thread]

Well, I am using ***Panda Wireless PAU07*** wireless adapter.

And, by default login credentials are **user:password** is **freebsd:freebsd** and **root:root**.

```
freebsd@generic:~ % uname -a
FreeBSD generic 12.0-CURRENT FreeBSD 12.0-CURRENT #0 r335317: Mon Jun 18 17:37:04 UTC 2018     root@releng3.nyi.freebsd.org:/usr/obj/usr/src/arm64.aarch64/sys/GENERIC  arm64
freebsd@generic:~ %
```

Here, `dmesg`:

```
freebsd@generic:~ % dmesg
KDB: debugger backends: ddb
KDB: current backend: ddb
Copyright (c) 1992-2018 The FreeBSD Project.
Copyright (c) 1979, 1980, 1983, 1986, 1988, 1989, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994
        The Regents of the University of California. All rights reserved.
FreeBSD is a registered trademark of The FreeBSD Foundation.
FreeBSD 12.0-CURRENT #0 r335317: Mon Jun 18 17:37:04 UTC 2018
    root@releng3.nyi.freebsd.org:/usr/obj/usr/src/arm64.aarch64/sys/GENERIC arm64
FreeBSD clang version 6.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_600/final 326565) (based on LLVM 6.0.0)
WARNING: WITNESS option enabled, expect reduced performance.
VT: init without driver.
KLD file umodem.ko is missing dependencies
KLD file if_run.ko is missing dependencies
Starting CPU 1 (1)
Starting CPU 2 (2)
Starting CPU 3 (3)
FreeBSD/SMP: Multiprocessor System Detected: 4 CPUs
random: unblocking device.
random: entropy device external interface
MAP 8000000 mode 2 pages 8
MAP 39f36000 mode 2 pages 1
MAP 3b3aa000 mode 2 pages 1
MAP 3f100000 mode 1 pages 1
kbd0 at kbdmux0
ofwbus0: <Open Firmware Device Tree>
simplebus0: <Flattened device tree simple bus> on ofwbus0
ofw_clkbus0: <OFW clocks bus> on ofwbus0
clk_fixed0: <Fixed clock> on ofw_clkbus0
clk_fixed1: <Fixed clock> on ofw_clkbus0
regfix0: <Fixed Regulator> on ofwbus0
regfix1: <Fixed Regulator> on ofwbus0
psci0: <ARM Power State Co-ordination Interface Driver> on ofwbus0
local_intc0: <BCM2836 Interrupt Controller> mem 0x40000000-0x400000ff on simplebus0
intc0: <BCM2835 Interrupt Controller> mem 0x7e00b200-0x7e00b3ff irq 20 on simplebus0
gpio0: <BCM2708/2835 GPIO controller> mem 0x7e200000-0x7e2000b3 irq 22,23 on simplebus0
gpiobus0: <OFW GPIO bus> on gpio0
generic_timer0: <ARMv7 Generic Timer> irq 0,1,2,3 on ofwbus0
Timecounter "ARM MPCore Timecounter" frequency 19200000 Hz quality 1000
Event timer "ARM MPCore Eventtimer" frequency 19200000 Hz quality 1000
bcm_dma0: <BCM2835 DMA Controller> mem 0x7e007000-0x7e007eff irq 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19 on simplebus0
bcmwd0: <BCM2708/2835 Watchdog> mem 0x7e100000-0x7e100027 on simplebus0
bcmrng0: <Broadcom BCM2835 RNG> mem 0x7e104000-0x7e10400f on simplebus0
mbox0: <BCM2835 VideoCore Mailbox> mem 0x7e00b880-0x7e00b8bf irq 21 on simplebus0
gpioc0: <GPIO controller> on gpio0
uart0: <PrimeCell UART (PL011)> mem 0x7e201000-0x7e201fff irq 24 on simplebus0
uart0: console (115200,n,8,1)
spi0: <BCM2708/2835 SPI controller> mem 0x7e204000-0x7e204fff irq 26 on simplebus0
spibus0: <OFW SPI bus> on spi0
spibus0: <unknown card> at cs 0 mode 0
spibus0: <unknown card> at cs 1 mode 0
iichb0: <BCM2708/2835 BSC controller> mem 0x7e804000-0x7e804fff irq 37 on simplebus0
bcm283x_dwcotg0: <DWC OTG 2.0 integrated USB controller (bcm283x)> mem 0x7e980000-0x7e98ffff,0x7e006000-0x7e006fff irq 43,44 on simplebus0
usbus0 on bcm283x_dwcotg0
sdhci_bcm0: <Broadcom 2708 SDHCI controller> mem 0x7e300000-0x7e3000ff irq 46 on simplebus0
mmc0: <MMC/SD bus> on sdhci_bcm0
fb0: <BCM2835 VT framebuffer driver> on simplebus0
fbd0 on fb0
VT: initialize with new VT driver "fb".
fb0: 656x416(656x416@0,0) 24bpp
fb0: fbswap: 1, pitch 1968, base 0x3eb33000, screen_size 818688
pmu0: <Performance Monitoring Unit> irq 50 on simplebus0
cpulist0: <Open Firmware CPU Group> on ofwbus0
cpu0: <Open Firmware CPU> on cpulist0
cpu1: <Open Firmware CPU> on cpulist0
cpu2: <Open Firmware CPU> on cpulist0
cpu3: <Open Firmware CPU> on cpulist0
gpioled0: <GPIO LEDs> on ofwbus0
gpioled0: <led0> failed to map pin
gpioled0: <led1> failed to map pin
cryptosoft0: <software crypto>
Timecounters tick every 1.000 msec
usbus0: 480Mbps High Speed USB v2.0
iicbus0: <OFW I2C bus> on iichb0
iic0: <I2C generic I/O> on iicbus0
ugen0.1: <DWCOTG OTG Root HUB> at usbus0
uhub0: <DWCOTG OTG Root HUB, class 9/0, rev 2.00/1.00, addr 1> on usbus0
mmcsd0: 16GB <SDHC USD00 0.2 SN 3AC34AE0 MFG 02/2016 by 156 SO> at mmc0 50.0MHz/4bit/65535-block
Release APs...done
CPU  0: ARM Cortex-A53 r0p4 affinity:  0
 Instruction Set Attributes 0 = <Trying to mount root from ufs:/dev/ufs/rootfs [rw]...
CRC32>
 Instruction Set Attributes 1 = <>
         Processor Features 0 = <AdvSIMD,Float,EL3 32,EL2 32,EL1 32,EL0 32>
         Processor Features 1 = <0>
      Memory Model Features 0 = <4k Granule,64k Granule,MixedEndian,S/NS Mem,16bit ASID,1TB PA>
      Memory Model Features 1 = <>
      Memory Model Features 2 = <32b CCIDX,48b VA>
             Debug Features 0 = <2 CTX Breakpoints,4 Watchpoints,6 Breakpoints,PMUv3,Debug v8>
             Debug Features 1 = <0>
         Auxiliary Features 0 = <0>
         Auxiliary Features 1 = <0>
CPU  1: ARM Cortex-A53 r0p4 affinity:  1
CPU  2: ARM Cortex-A53 r0p4 affinity:  2
CPU  3: ARM Cortex-A53 r0p4 affinity:  3
WARNING: WITNESS option enabled, expect reduced performance.
Warning: no time-of-day clock registered, system time will not be set accurately
uhub0: 1 port with 1 removable, self powered
ugen0.2: <vendor 0x0424 product 0x9514> at usbus0
uhub1 on uhub0
uhub1: <vendor 0x0424 product 0x9514, class 9/0, rev 2.00/2.00, addr 2> on usbus0
uhub1: MTT enabled
uhub1: 5 ports with 4 removable, self powered
ugen0.3: <vendor 0x0424 product 0xec00> at usbus0
smsc0 on uhub1
smsc0: <vendor 0x0424 product 0xec00, rev 2.00/2.00, addr 3> on usbus0
smsc0: chip 0xec00, rev. 0002
miibus0: <MII bus> on smsc0
smscphy0: <SMC LAN8700 10/100 interface> PHY 1 on miibus0
smscphy0:  10baseT, 10baseT-FDX, 100baseTX, 100baseTX-FDX, auto
ue0: <USB Ethernet> on smsc0
ue0: Ethernet address: b8:27:eb:b5:5b:d2
ugen0.4: <Ralink 802.11 n WLAN> at usbus0
lo0: link state changed to UP
smsc0: chip 0xec00, rev. 0002
ue0: link state changed to DOWN
run0 on uhub1
run0: <1.0> on usbus0
run0: MAC/BBP RT5592 (rev 0x0222), RF RT5592 (MIMO 2T2R), address 9c:ef:d5:fe:18:45
ieee80211_load_module: load the wlan_amrr module by hand for now.
wlan0: Ethernet address: 9c:ef:d5:fe:18:45
run0: firmware RT3071 ver. 0.33 loaded
wlan0: link state changed to UP
freebsd@generic:~ %
```

And, I am not sure about Raspberry Pi 1 because I don't have that. But, I think currently all supports.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the last answer to this question: [FreeBSD - easiest way to install on my RPi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3288/freebsd-easiest-way-to-install-on-my-rpi/82224#82224) it is pretty easy these days, I have it running on all of the "big" boards (version 1 through 3) in my collection, I suspect that it would run on a Zero as well, but I don't have one to try.