# Is it possible to run FreeBSD for ARMv8/arm64/64-bit on the Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: pi-3, 64-bit, freebsd

Is there a current FreeBSD ARMv8 64-bit variant (possibly 11 or 12 as of late 2017) available that will run on the Raspberry Pi 3?

Is any documentation, especially a howto available with details? Any specific recommendations welcome as relates to the goal of running an armv8 64bit variant of FreeBSD on the RPI3.

Comment: I may be completely wrong here, but have you seen: https://wiki.freebsd.org/arm64/rpi3? Last edit April 2017. "There is no package repo for 12-CURRENT, but the package repo for 11 can be used on 12-CURRENT by telling pkg to use the FreeBSD 11 aarch64 ABI"

Comment: Thanks @QuintinBalsdon, I noted the edit date too and think that it's not current. Was hoping to hear a direct answer from someone with experience simply so myself and others don't spend time chasing the wrong solution(s). Possibly related: http://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/snapshots/arm64/ http://www.raspbsd.org/raspberrypi.html

Comment: Cool - hope you come right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. Take a look at the [Raspberry Pi entry on the FreeBSD Wiki](https://wiki.freebsd.org/FreeBSD/arm/Raspberry%20Pi) and also this [question and (especially the last) answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3288/freebsd-easiest-way-to-install-on-my-rpi/82224#82224).