# Can I run FreeBSD on my Pi?

Tags: software-installation, freebsd

There are a number of questions asking about installing/running FreeBSD on the Pi – it looks like there are a lot of problems. Is FreeBSD runnable on the Pi? How can I get started?

Comment: The reason I added this question is that many of the older questions were about  specific and "out of date" problems. I thought it would be a good thing to have a more generic and maintainable question and answer(s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot has changed, for the better, since the early days of FreeBSD on the Pi. In my experience installing and running a recent version (11 or 12) is pretty painless these days.

Here are the steps that work for me on the "big" boards – I don't have a Pi Zero so I can't speak to them:

1. Download an SD card image (both [STABLE](ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/snapshots/arm/armv6/ISO-IMAGES) and [CURRENT](ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/snapshots/arm/armv7/ISO-IMAGES/12.0/) images are available, for version 3 boards [look here for the 64-bit CURRENT build](ftp://ftp.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD/snapshots/arm64/aarch64/ISO-IMAGES/12.0)) details of what is working are on the [wiki](https://wiki.freebsd.org/FreeBSD/arm/Raspberry%20Pi).
2. Decompress the image

   `xz --decompress ...`
3. Then `dd` the image to an empty SD or microSD card

   `dd if=<FreeBSD image file> of=/dev/<SD card mount> bs=1M`
4. Install the card in your Pi and apply power to boot.

Once the Pi is up and running, login – ssh, keyboard & display, or serial all work (for credentials use `freebsd/freebsd` or you can also login with `root/root` if you're on a serial line or the keyboard) and have fun.

If you are doing a headless install it may be a trick to get `ssh` to connect to the Pi. [Find Raspberry PI address on local network](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13936/find-raspberry-pi-address-on-local-network) gives some good techniques for finding the IP address assigned to your Pi.

Once you have it:

```
ssh freebsd@W.X.Y.Z
```

should do the trick.

You can find more info on the [FreeBSD Wiki](https://wiki.freebsd.org/FreeBSD/arm/Raspberry%20Pi).

Comment: Are the images up to date for running on `RPi 3B+`?

Comment: The latest (20180329) ones don't seem to be, they are hanging for me on network configuration on a Pi 3B and I've heard reports of problems on the 3B+ as well.